# Javascript: Can the forward line be executed before the current finishes?

Tags: javascript, html, css-transitions, settimeout

Last days I've faced a situation that almost got me insane. May be an stupidness of mine, but I really think this question can't be explored without thinking at OS's process escalonation and stuff.

The question is the following: Imagine I have a little red square with a click event:

```
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = setOpacity1;
```

The function `setOpacity1` is responsible for making another square - this one black and bigger - appear. First, it sets the display of this square to `block`
(it was `none` before); Secondly, it sets it's opacity to 1 (it was 0 before):

```
function setOpacity(){
    document.querySelector("#square").style.display = "block";
    document.querySelector("#square").style.opacity = 1;
}
```

But here we have a particularity: the change of opacity of the black square has a `transition` associated with it. So, the expected behaviour is that the square appears slowly, passing of "100% white" to "100% black".

But it does not occurs. However, this behaviour is achieved with `this` code:

```
document.querySelector("#button").onclick = setOpacity1;

    function setOpacity2(){
        document.querySelector("#square").style.opacity = 1;
    }

    function setOpacity1(){
        document.querySelector("#square").style.display = "block";
        setTimeout(setOpacity2,20);
    }
```

So, it seems to me that, in the first case, the change of opacity starts **before** the change of display...then, when the display finally gets set, the opacity's transition gets "broked". In the second case, I order the browser to wait a bit before it sets the opacity, what gives him time to set the display before.

Does this argument makes any sense? If not, what is happening here?

Fiddle of the code not working: https://jsfiddle.net/zjoeyhdz/

Fiddle of the code working:     https://jsfiddle.net/sj8vzuhx/

Comment: Different browsers have different behaviors. In Internet Explorer 11, both fiddles work fine.

Comment: @www.admiraalit.nl Sorry. Try it on Google Chrome.

Answer (score 2):

I guess it works as follows.
When the statement `document.querySelector("#square").style.... = ....` is executed, the browser does not immediately change the view, it just remembers the new style. When JavaScript execution has finished, it applies all style changes, but not necessarily in the order of the execution of the statements. In some browsers, it will do the `display` first and then the `opacity` (like in IE11, which works fine with both your fiddles) and in other browsers, it will happen the other way around (Chrome, Firefox).

Yes, your workaround will solve the problem for all browsers.